# File scope and access rules

Tags: c++

I saw something like the following in a IKM test, the code is in a single file:

```
class A{

public:
    int a;
    A();

protected:
    int x;

private:
    int y;

};

void ARandomFunction(){
    //Implementation
}
```

which variables of class A can ARandomFunction() access? Generally speaking what can be accessed if the decalarations are all in the same file?

Comment: It's no different to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Those variables will be per-instance (non-static member variables), so you first need to create an object to access them. Only `public` members can be accessed from a free-standing function unless the function is declared `friend` of that class in which case all members can be accessed.

That said it doesn't matter if they are in the same file or not. Once the class definition is visible where the function is implemented the members can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Being in the same file changes nothing, your function can only access `a` as it is `public` and your function is not a member of `A` (for the `private` members) nor a sub class of it (for the `protected` members).

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, using your above example ARandomFUnction can access the public variables and functions regardless of inheritance. THe protected variables can only be accessed if ARandomFunction is contained in a class that inherits from or is a member of class A. Private variables and methods can only be accessed from the same class.

Comment: Assuming public inheritance model?

Comment: I believe so. Haven't programmed in C++ in quite a while so I apologize if my information is not as detailed as it should be.